# Docker container keeps restarting(crashing)

Tags: docker, crash, restart

my Docker container keeps restarting and I don't know why.

**You can try to reproduce the error with the container:**

`docker run -d \ --name egmrp-daemon \ --restart always \ -p 27200:27200 \ -v /path/to/whitelist.json:/home/node/whitelist.json \ ghcr.io/einfach-gaming/egmrp-daemon:latest`

**I got following error logs from the container logs:**

`yarn run v1.22.5 $ node ./dist/index.js {"level":50,"time":1638626537468,"err":{"type":"Error","message":"EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read","stack":"Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read\n    at Object.readSync (fs.js:592:3)\n    at tryReadSync (fs.js:366:20)\n    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:403:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/dist/index.js:46:10)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)\n    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)\n    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47","errno":-21,"syscall":"read","code":"EISDIR"},"msg":"Failed to load whitelist"} info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command. error Command failed with exit code 1.`

*Docker is functionally*

So yeah, I really don't know what to do anymore. I kinda tried everything.

**best reagards
j0e**

Comment: check the read permissions of directory you are mounting.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve], probably including at least the Dockerfile but possibly also enough of your Javascript source to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'm a noob at this ngl. Here's the GitHub site of it: https://github.com/Einfach-Gaming/egmrp-daemon